# rails render muliple partials in a single invocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Can someone suggest me a nice little way to return multiple things in a method and render all of them as different partials in the view?

```
def tasks
   if task1.present?
     ['task1_summary', task1: task1]
   if task2.present?
     ['task2_programs', task2: task2]
   if task3.present?
     ['task3', program: task3]
   else
     [empty: '']
   end
  end
```

In my view:

```
  = render *tasks
```

The above code would just render one partial.

I am trying to figure out a way that would return all the partials if all the above conditions are true

Comment: Why can't you return an array of arrays and then iterate over it in your view calling render for each one just as you're doing now?

Comment: i was trying to avoid any kind of logic in the views. but if thats the only way i can try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def tasks
tasks_array = []

   tasks_array <<  ['task1_summary', task1: task1] if task1.present?

   tasks_array << ['task2_programs', task2: task2] if task2.present?

   tasks_array << ['task3', program: task3] if task3.present?

end
```

would return an array of your tasks. You can then go through them with `.each` in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return an array of arguments which you then pass to the render call:

In Erb:

```
<% tasks.each do |task| %>
  <%= render task %>
<% end %>
```